# Send action from NSTextField when on key up instead of return

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, ibaction

I want to show the number of characters left for a new tweet, after a key has been lifted. Currently, this only happens if return is lifted:

```
- (IBAction)updateCharacterCountFromNewTweetField:(id)sender {
  [newTweetCharacterCount setIntValue:140 - [[sender stringValue] length]];
}
```

This action is connected to an **NSTextField** (NOT A UITextField!!):
[image]

This is terrible for users, because they want to see the character count immediately, not just after pressing return.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a delegate on the textfield and have it implement the [controlTextDidChange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidChange:) delegate method.

See also [Text Editing Programming Guide: Delegate Messages and Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/DelegatesAndNotif.html).

Comment: Ooh, stupid me. Why didn't I think of a delegate. >.< THANKS :'D